# How does processing of T1 images affect tractography after registering the DWI to T1?

Tags: neuroimaging

At the moment I believe that registering (aligning) Diffusion Weighted Images (DWI) to T1 images only allows for the DWI to have a parcellation basis, and otherwise it does not give much information. 
As far as I know the construction of fiber tracts only uses information derived from the DWI images, so any manipulation made to the T1 images during its processing (e.g. through the basic freesurfer pipeline) should not affect the final tracts that you obtain, nor their measures of FA -fractional anisotropy- or MD -medial diffusivity- for example.

Is such assumption right? I think that I might be wrong since there must be a point to the DWI to T1 registration other than allowing for parcellation of the brain, but I just cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Hi, could you provide a bit more context to your question. E.g., what do the abbreviations mean?